# The following android code is not giving desired result

Tags: java, android

I wanted to make a clickable button such that when I click it, it would display a Text message. I wrote the following code:

```
activity_main.xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.quiztime.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/football"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/football"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/texty"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java file:

```
package com.example.android.quiztime;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.football);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texty);
            textView.setText("Click success");
        }
    });

}

}
```

I also tried to change the ImageButton to an ImageView and try a setOnClickListener to that. But in vain. Please show me where I am going wrong.

Comment: If you manually set the text of your texty `TextView` in the layout file does it show? Your layout file doesn't seem valid unless that isn't the whole thing.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Wow!! I set the text manually and the next time I ran it it worked.. Thanks a lot.. I set the text manually to Hello 
And the next time I clicked it it changed to "Click Success"

Answer (score 0):

You can add `android:onClick` into your xml file

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.quiztime.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/football"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="pritnText"
    android:id="@+id/football"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/texty"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton imageButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.football);
    }

    public void printText(View v) {
        Log.d("DEBUG","WORKS");
    }
}
```